# Is it possible to send CAN BUS information using FPD link?

Tags: can, deserialiser

I am using below [serializer](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ds90ub925q-q1.pdf?ts=1708684608445&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) and [de serializer](https://www.ti.com/product/DS90UB926Q-Q1) in my design. The communication is happening via FPD LINK.

The block diagram is given below.

[image]

I have a CAN bus connected between the these two boards.

**My question is it possible to send CAN BUS information using FPD link ?.**

If it is possible means I can reduce one connector in my board

Comment: I think you need a bidirectional link for CAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a CAN bus through those chips. You can use a custom connector with both FPD-Link 3 and CAN bus. Or since the chips allow for I2C bus which is bi-directional, you could use a CAN bus controller with I2C bus. Or just use I2C if you can do without CAN.

Comment: Thank you. For FPD we need to use dedicated FAKRA connectors l believe. Please correct me if l am wrong